# How To save from my list in TextFile?

Tags: c#

I need to save my `List<Cupon>` to a text file. I am using this code:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\urim.sadiku\Desktop\Loja.txt", Cupo.ToString());
List<string> myList = new List<string>(Cupo.ToString().Split(','));
```

but the output in txtFile is:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LojeShperblyese2.Coupon]

Note : I need to save with `Split()`, but I don't know how to do that.

What do I need to do to save my list correctly?

Comment: You need to show us your definition of `Cupon`.

Comment: I realize English may not be your first language, but it makes it tough for us when the words are not consistent.  Are Cupon, Cupo, and Coupon referring to the same class?

Comment: No it is not my first language, i am from Albania, but Cupo is name of List, Coupon is name of class :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `ToString` method return type name, if it is not overriden in subclass.

Try to use

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\urim.sadiku\Desktop\Loja.txt",
                 string.Join(",", Cupo));
```

This assumes, that you have implemented `ToString` method corrrectly on your `LojeShperblyese2.Coupon` class

Comment: Yes it Work in first time..but when i try to save second time hes not work :S.

Comment: in first time i write my id 1 and name UUU and it saved..
in second time i write id 2 and name SSS and it saved but it save override first.. if you understand me

Comment: If you need to append file contents, use `File.AppendAllText` instead of `File.WriteAllText`

Answer (score 1):

`ToString` on `List` won't concatenate all elements of the list and return that, you'd need a custom implementation for such (or maybe there's an existing type that *does* behave like this, but not `List`).

Note the name of the method you're calling, particularly the `Text` part.

To correct your specific case, you'd need to define a `string` variable, and loop all elements of the list while building the output to write (`youstring += item`), then use `File.WriteAllText(yourstring)` - or some variation of this method, of which no doubt you could ask anyone on SO for a method to 'do it in one line?!'.

However, you could use [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx), which will do the same thing for you but with handling the iteration of each element for you.

Answer (score 0):

I should add that you should override `ToString()` Method of class `Coupon` to return your desired string that you want to be written to file, then Ilya Ivanov's answer will work.